# Es6 React Arrow function behaviour

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, browserify, arrow-functions

I'm trying to get into React using Borwserify, Watchify, Babelfiy (with ES2015 preset).

Could anyone please explain, why this is working...

```
export default class HelloWorld extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        username: 'Tyler McGinnis'
    }

    this.handleChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({username: e.target.value})
    };


}

render() {

    return (
        <div>
            Hello {this.state.username} <br />
            Change Name: <input type="text" value={this.state.username} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

and this code isn't (arrow function outside constructor)...

```
export default class HelloWorld extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        username: 'Tyler McGinnis'
    }
}


handleChange = (e) => {
   this.setState({username: e.target.value})
};

render() {

    return (
        <div>
            Hello {this.state.username} <br />
            Change Name: <input type="text" value={this.state.username} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

The last one gives me an error, that is:

```
Unexpected token (18:17)

handleChange = ((e) => {
            ^
       this.setState({username: e.target.value})
} );
```

All I can find on the Internet tells me, that both syntaxes should work, but they don't. this happens with the ES2015 babel preset set correctly (proof by compiling version one without an issue).

What am I missing? Why can't I have an arrow function outside the constructor (or probably any other "regular" function in the class)?

Any help will be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Because that's an ES7-proposed extension. This syntax does not work in ES6, your compiler is correct.

Comment: You can't have arrow functions as a class method in es6

Comment: wow that was quick. thank you both! is there a es7 preset for babel by chance...? or should i just leave it?

Comment: http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-1/

Answer (score 2):

In ES6 / ES2015 you can't have arrow functions as a class method.

Define handleChange as normal method.

```
handleChange(e){
   this.setState({username: e.target.value});
}
```

Bind handleChange with this in the constructor function

```
constructor() {
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
}
```

Comment: I think this is allowed in ES7 or experimental versions. Not sure.

Answer (score 2):

This is an ES7 stage-1 feature called [Class properties transform](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/), you can install `babel-preset-stage-1` or use a plugin `transform-class-properties` to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use ES7 features, you need the babel plugin

transform-class-properties( you  need this one for arrow functions)

- yarn add babel-plugin-transform-class-properties   --dev
- yarn add babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread --dev

and you config **webpack**  something else like this

```
.configureBabel(function(babelConfig) {
        babelConfig.plugins = ["transform-object-rest-spread","transform-class-properties"]
    })
```